# How to disable PHP functions in Wordpress?

Tags: php

I have a Wordpress site running on my local network. I want to disable dangerous functions like system and exec as a safety precaution. This site is run with a simple PHP server instead of apache2 or nginx.

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8001 -f /var/www/html/wordpress/
```

Since, disabling functions in the /etc/php/7.x/apache2/php.ini won't matter. I could disable these functions in the /etc/php/7.x/cli/php.ini, but I just want them to be disabled to the Wordpress site.Is there a way that I can go around this. My final goal is to prevent execution of those functions through the Wordpress site.

Comment: For the record, this question is likely off-topic and not related to WordPress. Better to ask this kind of question over at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `php.ini` file for your WP instance and add the `disable_functions` directive to it. Then, start the PHP server with `-c` option, such as `php -S 127.0.0.1:8001 -c /path/to/php.ini -f /var/www/html/wordpress/`.